# IntelliJ - maven.config and jvm.config files are ignored by IntelliJ run configuration

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, config

In my Maven project, I have a `.mvn` folder where my `maven.config` and `jvm.config` files are located for project-specific arguments. I develop with IntelliJ and when I run a maven configuration (either with the bundled maven or a custom maven installation), the arguments in those files are not picked up during the build.
However, when I run the same maven goal over the terminal with a custom maven installation, the arguments all get picked up.

How do I have to configure IntelliJ so the `maven.config` and `jvm.config` are being picked up?

Comment: If I remember correctly IDEA IntelliJ nor Eclipse do support those things..

Comment: It is not supported. Here are related requests: [IDEA-197658](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197658) [IDEA-205178](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-2051780)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for `maven.config` has been finally added in IntelliJ 2021.3.

> It is now possible to configure the Maven settings for each project in the *.mvn/maven.config* file in *Preferences/ Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Maven* by selecting *Use settings from .mvn/maven.config*.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/11/intellij-idea-2021-3/#build_tools